# why does my (alternative to !!) function have this type

Tags: haskell

Being a little bit frustrated over the error messages some prelude functions (like !!) give, I tried to write a different version.

```
--(!!!) :: (Show a,Integral b)=> [a]->b->a
as !!! y=f as y
    where f (x:xs) b= if b==0
                      then x
                      else f xs (b-1)
          f [] _= error "!!!: list "++(show as)++" has less than "++show y++" elements"
```

However the function type is

```
*Handydandy> :type (!!!)
(!!!) :: (Show a, Num a, Eq a) => [[Char]] -> a -> [Char]
```

I do not understand why the first argument is inferred to be a list of Strings here instead of just a list of show instances. Could anybody explain?

Comment: Note that your `f` helper isn't really useful—`(!!!)` can just call itself recursively.

Comment: @dfeuer It wouldn't actually be equivalent, the way he has it defined means that if the index is out of bounds the error message will contain the original list and index passed to `!!!`, which isn't possible (to my knowledge) without a helper function.

Comment: @bheklilr, ah yes, I didn't notice that. I don't usually pay too much attention to the contents of error messages! I should note that doing things like this can have a performance impact as it needs to hold on to a pointer to the front of the list until it completes successfully.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need some  parenthesis (or a `$`) in the last line:

```
error ("!!!: list "++(show as)++" has less than "++show y++" elements")
```

Right now its being parsed as

```
(error "!!!: list ") ++ (show as) ++ " has less than " ++ show y ++" elements"
```

which makes Haskell think that `(!!!)` is returning a string, which then would mean that its input must be a list of strings.

Answer (score 6):

It's because of your use of `error`.  The type of `error` is `String -> a`, and the way you've typed it the compiler sees it as

```
f [] _ = (error "!!!: list ") ++ (show as) ++ " has less than " ++ (show y) ++ " elements"
```

Since you have a value of type `a` concatenated with a `String` (i.e. `error "!!!: list " ++ show as`), then `a` must be `String`, and so the return type of `f` must be `String`.  You have `f (x:xs) 0 = x`, so `x` must have type `String`, and therefore `xs :: [String]`.

You can fix this with `$`:

```
f [] _ = error $ "!!!: list " ++ show as ++ " has less than " ++ show y ++ " elements"
```

And now the type of this function is `(!!!) :: (Show t, Show a, Num a, Eq a) => [t] -> a -> t`, more like what you want.

However, if you want a better way to handle this in code instead of just in a runtime error message you can use the `Maybe` data type, or even the `Either` type if you want more information:

```
(!!?) :: [a] -> Int -> Maybe a
[]     !!? _ = Nothing
(x:_)  !!? 0 = Just x
(_:xs) !!? n = xs !!? (n - 1)

(!!^?) :: [a] -> Int -> Either ([a], Int) a
ys !!^? m = go ys m
    where
        go []     _ = Left (ys, m)
        go (x:_)  0 = Right x
        go (_:xs) n = go xs $ n - 1
```

Then you could have

```
showIndexError :: Show a => Either ([a], Int) a -> String
showIndexError (Left (xs, n)) = "!!^?: list " ++ show xs ++ " has less than " ++ show y ++ " elements"
showIndexError (Right x) = show x
```

Comment: thanks. I'll probably graduate to maybe and its ilk some day.